# Can GLFW and Qt share the same OpenGL context and use GLEW functions to render to both surfaces?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, glfw, glew

I am writing an OpenGL engine that is not tied to any windowing framework. It uses `GLEW` to retrieve the `OpenGL` functions. It works perfect with `GLFW`, but can't figure out how to get to GLFW share its context with `Qt` to be able to use `GLEW` functions on both of them.

More specifically, I want to create a `GLFW` window and use its context in an `QOpenGLWidget` and vice versa but be able to use `GLEW` provided functions to render to both windows.

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  You state that you're trying to write a framework agnostic OpenGL based engine but then say you want to tie it to GLEW, GLFW *and* QOpenGLWidget.  Better to design your engine to be completely independent of any of those: just leave it to the user of your engine to create the context in whatever way is convenient for them.